# Mark up Editor Support for Content Publishing Website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am working on content publishing website which have will multimedia markup editor support using that creator can post content (similar to medium editor). We are using azure for hosting our resources.

**Server Side**

We are planning to store complete blog document in Azure CDN and reference document in Cosmos DB with additional metadata. Each multimedia will be stored in Azure CDN and will be referenced markup document.

**Frontend Side**

I am new to frontend development and React JS. How do we handle :

- How do we handle this on creator side for adding multimedia and Markup support. Any reference for this
- On actual reader website how do we render this document.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome! There's really no way to answer your question objectively; this is really an opinion-based (and recommendation-based) question, across a very broad topic - you're covering both front-end and back-end as well, with multiple areas of discussion (and Stack Overflow isn't set up for discussion). I suggest trying something out, and then posting a question specific to an issue you run into.

Comment: Also: Please be mindful of tagging. As written, this question really isn't related to Cosmos DB at all (aside from mentioning that you're using it). I removed that tag, accordingly.